# Classificaion with fitcsvm in matlab produces an error

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I had tried the following code

```
clear all;close all;
data =  [27 9   2
11.6723281  28.93422177 2
25  9   2
23  8   2
5.896096039 23.97745722 1
21  6   2
21.16823369 5.292058423 2
4.242640687 13.43502884 1
22  6   2];
Attributes = data(:,1:2);
Classes = data(:,3);
train = [1 3 4 5 6 7];
testInds = [2 8 9];
test1 = data(testInds,1:2);
YTest =data(testInds,3);
%%# Train
svmStruct = svmtrain(Attributes(train,:),Classes(train),'ShowPlot',true);

 SVMModel = fitcsvm(Attributes(train,:),Classes(train))
 classOrder = SVMModel.ClassNames
sv = SVMModel.SupportVectors;
figure
gscatter(data(:,1),data(:,2),Classes)
hold on
plot(sv(:,1), sv(:,2),'ko','MarkerSize',10)
legend('good','bad','Support Vector')
hold off
[label,score] = predict(SVMModel,test1);
% [predict_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = predict(SVMModel,test1)
table(YTest(1:2),label(1:2),score(1:10,2),'VariableNames',...
    {'TrueLabel','PredictedLabel','Score'})
```

I tried the above code. First two column are my data and last column is the group id. SVMModel is the classification. I'm getting error as

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Untitled (line 34)
table(YTest(1:2),label(1:2),score(1:10,2),'VariableNames',...
I tried to test an instance. But both statements produces an error

```
[label,score] = predict(SVMModel,test);
 label           = svmclassify(SVMModel, test);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply flipped predictors and labels - it is `fitcsvm(predictors,labels)`, or in your case `fitcsvm(Attributes(train,:),Classes(train))`

edit:

```
plot(sv(:,1), sv(:,2),'ko','MarkerSize',10) % you obviously do not want to plot the same data twice in the same plot...
```

For the prediction: `[predict_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(Classes(test), Attributes(test,:), SVMModel);` looks fine.

Comment: My mistake, instead of `model` it has to be `SVMModel`, corrected it. `train = [1 3 4 5 6 7]` is perfectly fine. What exactly do you want to plot? currently the training vectors are plotted and the elements which are used as supports for the model vectors have a circle around them if I interpret the code correctly. This looks perfectly nice to me if you want to know how the vectors divide your data.

Comment: svmpredict is part of `LIBSVM`. I assumed you had that. If not, you can either install it (just google "LIBSVM matlab" for some tutorials) or use the built-in function `predict`. (`[label,score,cost] = predict(SVMModel,Attributes(test,:));`

Comment: If you want to estimate the predictor performance, cross validation is anyway the usual way to go, you can do that with `crossval`